# How to fix .repo/repo/main.py invalid syntax issue (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: python, repo

Whenever i want to `repo init -u https://github.com/Pelagicore/pelux-manifests.git -b master`
i get this error:

```
File "/home/Batman/pelux/.repo/repo/main.py", line 79
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have looked up several solution on the internet googled so many solutions but none of them seem to work for me, does anyone know how i can fix this? i know it has something to do with python parsing but i am not sure how to fix this issue, If someon has a solution to this please do share

Comment: It looks very much as though you are executing Python 3 code in a Python 2 interpreter. It is virtually certain the line 79 is a `print()` function call and the interpreter is expecting a Python 2 `print` statement.

Comment: In Python 2, `print(something, file=sys.stderr)` is not a function call, but an attempt to create a tuple from the values `something` and `file=sys.stderr`, but the latter is not a valid expression in Python.

Comment: I fixed your tags. Note that `repo` is a Python script.